# Grails regenerate Eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, grails

I just upgrade Grails to 1.2.0. How can get Grails to regenerate the Eclipse `.classpath` file? It's currently pointing to the old Grails' JARs.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the project node and select Configure|Convert to Grails Project. It'll setup a "Grails Dependencies" library pointing to the Grails jars, and it'll setup links to your plugin libs and folders. You will lose the entries for jars in the lib dir - my guess is that there's an assumption that you'll use Ivy for dependency management.

Comment: answered by question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107329/is-there-a-grails-command-to-regenerate-project-files-for-eclipse-or-sts

Answer (score 0):

there is an option to upgrade grails using command line. `"grails upgrade"`
That should upgrade your app..

before that you need to change your `grails_home` variable to point to your latest version.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project name in the "Project Explorer" -> choose "Properties"

In the "Properties for  window, look for the grails option on the left side.

Once in there, there should be a drop down for the grails version that the project was initially confugured/imported with. This should be changed to your new version.