# Is there a grails command to regenerate .project files for Eclipse or STS?

Tags: grails

I've checked out an existing Grails project and I want to import it into STS. However, STS refuses to recognize the source tree as a project, presumably because it can't find a .project file. So is there a 'grails' command that will create new .project (and .classpath and .settings/*) for this source tree?

Answer (score 10):

use

```
grails integrate-with --eclipse
```

I think this command has been added in Grails 1.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

"grails integrate-with --eclipse" does not work with Grails 3.1.3.  get Command not found error.

Guess I have to keep looking.

--- update

In Eclipse 4.5 (Mars.1):
File -> Import Gradle Project (STS) - select top of grail project
then hit Build Model button
Then Finish button.

Wait for lots of downloads and then Voila!  You have a project in Eclipse.

Comment: Just curious, can you import project Gradle in Eclipse?