# best way to configure Springsource Tool Suit (STS, eclipse) to work with grails

Tags: eclipse, grails, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am looking to the best way to configure eclipse or STS to work right with Grails.

I am working with the 2.3.2 version.
I have tried to set classpath the right way installing this plugin:
http://grails.org/plugin/eclipse-scripts

Also [this awnser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107329/is-there-a-grails-command-to-regenerate-project-files-for-eclipse-or-sts/3107531#3107531).

But I am having several issues:

- Autocomplete doesn't work, it shows this message when I hit CTRL+SPACE: "unavailable autocomplete"
- Multiple compilations errors (acording to STS, not to grails)
- None syntax highlight for gsp files.
- The project view looks horrible with all the links to plugins source paths

So I am thinking: Is this the best way to configure it?

Do you have a better way?

Lets collect all the tips and tricks to configure STS of the best way to work with grails.

thanks in advance

Comment: have you also installed the Groovy plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the M2 version of 2.3.3 and the Grails and Groovy support both have major improvements over previous versions. See http://blog.springsource.com/2010/07/19/grails-tooling-improvements-in-springsource-tool-suite-2-3-3-m2/

Comment: Thanks I am going to try it. Do you need to configure anything?

Comment: Not much, it works well for the most part. You do occasionally need to run 'Refresh Dependencies' from the Grails Tools menu (right-click on project). A fresh checkout from source control needs one commandline action ('grails compile' or 'grails run-app') to trigger installation of plugins and other Ivy resolution stuff, but that's a 1-time thing.